# pointer not being updated when passed between functions

Tags: c++, pointers, dll

So my main function looks like this:

```
void main {
    uint32 errmsg;
    uint32 mydata;
    if (LOG) {
        std::ofstream file;
        file.open(fileName,ios_base::app);
        file << "!!!mydata: " << mydata << ",&mydata: " << &mydata << endl;
        file.close();
    }
    errmsg = ReadReg32(0, 0, &mydata);
    if (LOG) {
        std::ofstream file;
        file.open(fileName,ios_base::app);
        file << "!!! returned mydata: " << mydata << ",&mydata: " << &mydata << endl;
        file.close();
    }
}
```

and calls ReadReg32 below:

```
static uint32 ReadReg32(uint32 brdNum, uint32 address, uint32 *data)
{
    std::ofstream file;
    if (LOG) {
        file.open(fileName,ios_base::app);
        file << "   ReadReg32: brdNum =" << brdNum << ", address =" << address << endl;
        file << "   ReadReg32 ... Data WAS:  " << *data << endl;
        file.close();
    }

    /* AD:TW Check if we need to do init */
    bool initstatus = checkDeferredInit();

    ADMXRC3_HANDLE phCard;
    ADMXRC3_STATUS status;

    //open card
    if((status = ADMXRC3_Open(brdNum, &phCard)) != ADMXRC3_SUCCESS)
        return status;

    //read data
    if((status = ADMXRC3_Read(phCard, NON_PREFETCHABLE_SPACE, 0, address, 4, &data)) != ADMXRC3_SUCCESS){
        ADMXRC3_Close(phCard);
        return status;
    }

    if (LOG) {
        file.open(fileName,ios_base::app);
        file << "   ReadReg32 ... Data IS:  " << data << ", &data: " << &data << ", Read status =" << status << endl;
        file.close();
    }

    //close card
    status = ADMXRC3_Close(phCard);

    if (LOG) {
        file.open(fileName,ios_base::app);
        file << "   ReadReg32 ... Close card status =" << status << ", Returning ..." << endl;
        file.close();
    }
    return status;
}
```

### The relevant output is this:

```
!!!mydata: 348,&mydata: 000000000012F050
   ReadReg32: brdNum =0, address =0
   ReadReg32 ... Data WAS:  348
checkDeferredInit
   ReadReg32 ... Data IS:  0000000081040102, &data: 000000000012EF30, Read status =0
   ReadReg32 ... Close card status =0, Returning ...
!!! returned mydata: 348,&mydata: 000000000012F050
```

---

where 0000000081040102 is the correct number i expect to see, but it never returns that to the calling function, i.e. mydata is never updated.

Interesting notes:

1. in ADMXRC3_Read, if I don't use &data, i get "incorrect" data values
2. in ADMXRC3_Read, the type for where i'm sticking in &data is
   supposed to be void *pbuffer?

Any thoughts are worth like a case of beer, or a moderately fine boxed wine.  ;)

I do appreciate any thoughts you have, this has me stumped...

Comment: have you tried (void *) data, instead of &data on the read?

Comment: Its very unclear what the question is here

Comment: "my main function looks like this: `void main {` " - I hope it doesn't.

Comment: @user2801266: Do you have some documentation for `ADMXRC3_Read()`? Knowing that it takes `void *pbuffer` is not very helpful, if it's taking a `void` pointer then it's going to be converting that into something else, and whatever you pass to it has to be something compatible. If you're not, then that would explain why you get "incorrect" data values when you don't use `&data`, which is almost certainly correct, and it also implies that using `&data` may be invisibly doing some really Bad Thing at some random memory location.

Comment: Why tagged with C? It's C++.

Answer (score 2):

Well at first glance it seems you are using `&` too much.

```
static uint32 ReadReg32(uint32 brdNum, uint32 address, uint32 *data)
{
 ....
//read data
    if((status = ADMXRC3_Read(phCard, NON_PREFETCHABLE_SPACE, 0, address, 4, &data)) != ADMXRC3_SUCCESS){
        ADMXRC3_Close(phCard);
        return status;
    }
```

Here in `read data` part, you are calling `ADMXRC3_Read` with `&data` param. But `data` is already pointer! So you actually pass adress of variable that is local to your function.

To fix this, call the `ADMXRC3_Read` with `data` only.

IMPORTANT: <strike>In C and C++ everything is passed by value!</strike> So the `data` is just an variable holding 32-bit number (if you have 32bit addresses), nothing more.

EDIT: In my note I was referring to this FAQ: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passbyref.html and I wrote it wrong. See the FAQ for more info.

Comment: "Everything is passed by value". Well, no. In C, arrays are the exception (passed by pointer to array), and in C++ you can explicitly pass-by-reference (`Type&`).

Comment: I was referring to this FAQ: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passbyref.html And my reference is indeed incorrect. I'll fix my post.